# Input resistance of biased amplifiers

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

What are the input resistances of the following biased amplifiers.
I know RG1||RG2 is the input resistance of the first one. But i can't understand how.
Is it RG+RD for the second one?

Comment: where did you get the formula for the last circuit from?

Answer (score 2):

1.) **First circuit**: Assuming that the gate voltage divider is connected to a voltage source (zero internal source resistance) both resistors can be regarded to be ground referenced (signal ground). Hence, as seen from the gate node, both resistors are in parallel and connected to ground. Therefore, **rin=RG1||RG2**.

2.) **Second circuit**: The feedback resistor RG is connected between the input node (gate) and a node that is NOT connected to signal ground. Rather it is connected to the drain node. During normal operation, this node has a signal voltage that is phase shifted by 180 deg (in comparison to the input signal at the gate).
Thus, the voltage DIFFERENCE across this resistor is larger than the input signal voltage. As a conseqence, there is a larger signal current through RG. Thus, this resistor - as seen from the input - seems to be SMALLER than its value indicates.
The corresponding calculation involves the input signal voltage AND the amplified voltage at the gate (corrected: at the **drain**). Thus, signal gain comes into play.
The result is 
**rin=RG/(1-G)**.
Note that G is the gain at the drain node (negative value due to phase inversion).

All calculation above are based on the assumption that the FET input resistance at the gate can be neglected. otherwise, it is in parallel to the given rin expressions.

Comment: For the second one, say, the input voltage is G. So, the output voltage will be -GV for a gain V. So, the current through Rg will be (V-(-GV))/Rg=((1+G)V)/Rg. And no current goes through the gate the input resistance will be Rg/(G+1). What am i getting wrong here?

Comment: ^sorry for gain G

Comment: I suppose, you have mixed G and V.

Comment: You have forgotten to take account of Rd in your answer.

Comment: @Andyaka: Rd is implicit, in the sense that it contributes to the equation for the gain of the stage.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the small signal circuit for the second case:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhNG1b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I already added the test generator \$V_p\$ (sorry, in Italian it's "tensione di Prova", so we use p. just a habit...).

If we can calculate \$I_p\$ then the resistance seen between gate and ground is \$R_{in}=\frac{v_p}{i_p}\$. Let's get started.

balance of currents on node drain:
$$i_{rd}+g_mv_{gs}=\frac{v_g-v_d}{R_g} \Rightarrow \frac{v_d}{R_d}+g_mv_p=\frac{v_p-v_d}{R_g}$$

Let's solve for \$v_d\$:
$$v_d=v_pR_d\frac{1-g_mR_g}{R_d+R_g}$$

(I'm skipping the algebra part, I bet you can figure it out)

Now we can write something for \$i_p\$:
$$i_p=\frac{v_p-v_d}{R_g}=v_p\frac{1}{R_g}[1-\frac{R_d}{R_g+R_d}(1-g_mR_g)]=...=v_p\frac{1+g_mR_d}{R_g+R_d}$$

And finally:

$$R_{in}=\frac{v_p}{i_p}=\frac{R_g+R_d}{1+g_mR_d}$$

That's quite near the other answer since the gain is \$g_mR_d\$.

For the first circuit, as stated, \$R_{in}=R_{g1}//R_{g2}=\frac{R_{g1}R_{g2}}{R_{g1}+R_{g2}}\$

Comment: Vladimir, you have a sign error in your 2nd equation. The common source amplifier is inverting so your 2nd equation cannot be correct; the sign of \$v_d\$ is opposite than of \$v_p\$.  When I do the algebra from the 1st equation, I get \$v_d = \frac{R_D}{R_D + R_G}(1 - g_mR_G)v_p = -\frac{R_D}{R_D + R_G}(g_mR_G - 1)v_p\$

Answer (score 1):

It is important to remember that here we're finding the AC or small-signal input resistance.

So, the first step is to *zero* the DC sources.  When this is done for the left-most schematic, note that the top of \$R_{G1}\$ is now connected to AC ground.

Thus, \$R_{G1}\$ and \$R_{G2}\$ parallel connected; both have one terminal connected to the gate and one terminal connected to ground.  The input resistance is then

$$R_{in} = R_{G1}||R_{G2}$$

For the right-most circuit, the most straightforward way to find the input resistance is to use superposition to write, by inspection, the input current:

$$i_{in} = \frac{v_{in}}{R_G + R_D} + i_d\frac{R_D}{R_G + R_D} $$

Since

$$i_d = g_mv_{in} $$

we have that

$$i_{in} = (\frac{v_{in}}{R_G + R_D} + v_{in}\frac{g_mR_D}{R_G + R_D} )$$

Thus,

$$R_{in} = \frac{v_{in}}{i_{in}} = \frac{R_G + R_D}{1 + g_m R_D}$$

If we assume \$g_m R_D >> 1\$, the input resistance is approximately

$$R_{in} \approx \frac{R_G + R_D}{ g_m R_D} = \frac{1 + \frac{R_G}{R_D}}{g_m}$$

---

I'd like to expand on LvW's answer.  Since the AC drain voltage is *proportional* to the AC gate voltage in the right-most circuit

$$v_d = kv_g $$

and since the voltage across \$R_G\$ is the difference of these two node voltages

$$v_{R_G} = v_g - v_d = v_g(1-k)$$

we can split \$R_G\$ into two separate resistors; one from gate to ground and one from drain to ground.

Since the current through \$R_G\$ is

$$i_{R_G} = \frac{v_g(1-k)}{R_G} $$

the resistor from gate to ground must have a value of

$$R'_G = \frac{R_G}{1-k}$$

This then is the input resistance

$$R_{in} = R'_G $$

The voltage across the resistor from drain to ground is just the AC drain voltage so its value must be

$$R'_D = \frac{v_d}{-i_{R_G}} = \frac{k}{k-1}R_G $$

Of course, to determine the actual values, we must know \$k\$ which can be written by inspection using superposition:

$$k = \frac{v_d}{v_g} = \frac{v_g \frac{R_D}{R_D + R_G} - i_d\cdot R_D||R_G}{v_g} =  \frac{v_g \frac{R_D}{R_D + R_G} - g_mv_g\cdot R_D||R_G}{v_g} = \frac{R_D}{R_D + R_G}(1 - g_mR_G) = - \frac{R_D}{R_D + R_G}(g_mR_G - 1)$$

Substituting into the equation for \$R'_G\$ yields

$$R'_G = R_{in}=\frac{R_G + R_D}{1 + g_m R_D}  $$

as previously found using the more straighforward calculation as presented in the first section.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. but as far as i remember, dependent voltage sources are not deactivated nor used as one of the sources in superposition.

Comment: @QuaziMishkatulAlam, one *can* use superposition with dependent sources.  See:   http://users.ece.gatech.edu/mleach/papers/superpos.pdf  *"Many introductory circuits texts state or imply that superposition of dependent sources cannot be used in linear circuit analysis... **A formal proof is presented that superposition of dependent sources is valid provided the controlling variable is not set to zero when the source is deactivated.**"*